# Imprimir int y double de un archivo .dat por consola

Tags: java, archivo

Quisiera poder imprimir los datos enteros y double de un archivo .dat creado en una clase y leido en otra pero al momento de leerlo solo muestra los caracteres o cadena String.

Clase de creacion y escritura en .dat

```
public class EscribirBinario {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File f = new File("binarioo.dat");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f, false);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

            //Escribimos una cadena
            dos.writeUTF("White True");
            //Escribimos un numero
            dos.writeInt(4);
            //Escribimos un numero
            dos.writeInt(15);

            //Escribimos un double
            dos.writeDouble(180.5);
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error E/S: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Luego en la clase leer, lee los caracteres de letras pero los de numero no, mostrando o espacios vacios o cuadros vacios

```
public class LeerBinario {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File f = new File("binarioo.dat");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);

            while (dis.available() > 0) {
                System.out.println(dis.available());

                byte[] bytes = new byte[30];
                dis.read(bytes);

                byte[] intbytes = new byte[4];
                dis.read(intbytes);

                byte[] doublebytes = new byte[8];
                dis.read(doublebytes);
                int c = 0;
                for (byte b : bytes) {
                    if (c <= 24) {
                        System.out.println((char) b);
                        c++;
                    }
                }                  
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error E/S: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

La idea es poder mostrar los datos en formato normal, en vez de esos caracteres no legibles, los comunes los enteros y doubles.

Comment: ¿Por qué 30 en `new byte[30]`?

Comment: el tamaño de lectura, lo que recorre

Comment: cuando leo el archivo que se crea con la primera clase, da el total de byte que es 30 , si uso 10 los caracteres se transforman en numeros

Comment: Te recomiendo que obtengas la representación hexadecimal del archivo y lo agregues a tu pregunta, y a partir de ahí podremos explicarte mejor. Aquí la pregunta clave es ¿Cómo sabes en dónde terminan los caracteres y dónde comienzan los números?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La longitud es <s>30</s> 28 (pensé que el OP estaba en lo correcto) porque [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)) escribe `\n` seguido del string `"White True"`, seguido de los 2 enteros, y el flotante.

Si hacemos la suma considerando cuánto ocupa cada uno obtendremos que el salto ocupa 2, el string ocupa 10, los enteros ocupan 8, y el flotante también 8, y `2 + 10 + 8 + 8 = 28`

Teniendo eso en cuenta, está claro que si queremos leer el string habrá que leer de los bytes del 3 al 13 (exclusivo), para leer los enteros habrá que leer del byte 13 al 17 y del 17 al 21. Para el flotante, habrá que leer del 21 al 29.

Para muestra de ello te dejo el siguiente código

```
File f = new File("binarioo.dat");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);

// ignoramos el "salto de línea"
dis.skip(2);

// leemos el string
byte[] string = new byte[10];
dis.read(string);
System.out.println(new String(string)); // confirmamos que el string sea correcto

// leemos el primer entero
byte[] entero1 = new byte[4];
dis.read(entero1);
System.out.println((entero1[0]<<24) & 0xff00_0000 | (entero1[1]<<16) & 0x00ff_0000 | (entero1[2]<<8) & 0x0000_ff00 | (entero1[3]) & 0x0000_00ff); // confirmamos que el entero sea correcto

// leemos el segundo entero
byte[] entero2 = new byte[4];
dis.read(entero2);
System.out.println((entero2[0]<<24) & 0xff00_0000 | (entero2[1]<<16) & 0x00ff_0000 | (entero2[2]<<8) & 0x0000_ff00 | (entero2[3]) & 0x0000_00ff); // confirmamos que el entero sea correcto

// leemos el double
byte[] flotante1 = new byte[8];
dis.read(flotante1);

assert dis.available() == 0; // técnicamente habremos llegado al final del archivo
```

**Ojo**: No es recomendable leerlo así puesto que pueden variar muchos factores como el encoding del archivo (qué pasa si escribes una ñ por ejemplo, no será guardada en 1 byte), y demás cosas.

Asimismo, es recomendable tener algún tipo de separador para hacer más fácil el parseo de la información (el salto de línea es frecuentemente ocupado). Espero haberte ayudado.

**Nota 1**: Se escribe el salto de línea al inicio porque si revisamos la documentación encontraremos lo siguiente respecto al método [writeUTF](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String))

> First, two bytes are written to the output stream as if by the writeShort method giving the number of bytes to follow. This value is the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the string

Entonces, es cierto que `writeUTF` no escribe un salto de línea, pero para este caso particular sí lo hace porque la longitud UTF-8 de `"White True"` es 10, que justamente corresponde al salto de línea. O sea, se escribe primero la longitud (10) como si se invocara a `writeShort`, y de hecho es por eso que al principio tenemos 2 bytes.

El OP menciona que son 30 bytes en lugar de 28. Al principio supuse que era correcto, también supuse que estaba en Windows y que por lo tanto el salto de línea era reemplazado por `\r\n`. Sin embargo, derivado de un comentario me di a la tarea de investigar si esto era cierto y me di cuenta que no es así. La longitud real es de 28 bytes.

Comment: Gracios brother, me ayudo mucho a comprender la lectura de los bytes.

Comment: `writeUTF()` no escribe automáticamente `\r\n`.

Comment: Gracias @Sal, ya ejecuté el programa en Windows y es cierto lo que dices, no escribe `\r\n` sino `\n`. Actualicé mi respuesta.

Comment: De hecho, tampoco es `\n`; debería ser la longitud de la cadena (10), que por casualidad es el mismo código ascii de salto de línea.

Comment: Así es @Sal, es la longitud en bytes de la cadena en UTF-8, de forma tal que `dos.writeUTF("pirólisis");` escribe también `\n`, a pesar que `"pirólisis".length() == 9`

Comment: No es `\n`, mide 10 por que `ó` ocupa dos bytes. Los saltos de línea no se escriben automáticamente.

Comment: @Sal, sí escribe `\n`, intenta correr el código. Otro ejemplo es `dos.writeUTF("⨕.")` que también escribe `\n` a pesar de que `"⨕.".length() == 4`. Doy estos ejemplos sólo para recalcar el hecho de que el número escrito previo al texto no depende de la longitud del texto (UTF-16), sino de los bytes requeridos para representarlo en UTF-8. Entiendo que los saltos de línea no se escriben automáticamente, tengo claro que si escribimos `dos.writeUTF("");` no vamos a ver `\n` sino `$`. Quizá me dí a entender mal, si tengo que corregir la redacción en mi respuesta dime y lo reviso.